# Conditional Formatting Less than issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using conditional formatting on 150 text boxes, if the value is >85% then background is green, if its <85% then the background is red.

Firstly, is there a quick way to set the formatting for all 150 of them quickly, instead of doing them one at a time

Secondly, I amusing the following expression to format my text box

```
Val([text168])>0.84
```

This works perfectly and the background is green.

When I use this code to set the background as red is does nothing the background stays white:

```
Val([text168])<0.85
```

I can not get my head around why this is happening

Comment: is this a continuous form? when you say you have 150 text boxes, is it just `[text168]` repeated for each record?

Comment: this might not be main issue but your operators overlap, better use 
`Val([text168])<0.85` and `Val([text168])>0.85`

Comment: I tried swapping the operators around but no success - Ye I have 150 textboxes each show a different record value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the number from 0.85 to a whole number of 85? It may be that the data is not directly bound to your table.

Hope this helps